# SQL Join select both tables' characteristics

Tags: sql, join

I would like to do a query which selects the best_offers' items which have a seller who has 'abc' as a password. The following query works, but it also select the seller's characteristics :

```
SELECT * FROM best_offers INNER JOIN seller ON best_offers.seller_id = seller.username
WHERE seller.pw='abc'
```

This is the result of the query :

![2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPrOB.jpg

However, I tried almost the same query on other tables and it works : it only select the cart's characteristics :

```
SELECT * FROM buy_it_now INNER JOIN cart ON buy_it_now.id = cart.item_id
WHERE cart.buyer_id = 'kimpaille'
```

This is the result of the query that works :

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMhTE.jpg

Comment: please provide the statements without the asterisks in query. since we don't know your schema, we do not know which columns of the result come from which table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want the offers, you would use:

```
SELECT bo.*
FROM best_offers bo INNER JOIN
     seller s
     ON bo.seller_id = s.username
WHERE s.pw = 'abc';
```

Only select the columns you need.  Further:

- Equating `seller_id` with `username` looks wrong.  Usually "id"s are not the same as a "name".
- Passwords should not be stored as cleartext.  Ever.  People tend to re-use passwords across different systems, so seeing someone else's password is a huge security risk.
- Table aliases make a query easier to write and to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM best_offers
WHERE
   EXISTS (
     SELECT * 
     FROM seller 
     WHERE username = best_offers.seller_id
           AND pw='abc'
   )
```

OR

```
SELECT best.*
FROM best_offers AS best
INNER JOIN seller AS s ON s.username = best.seller_id  AND s.pw = 'abc'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the columns only from `best_offers` table then just `select best_offers.*`

```
SELECT best_offers.* FROM best_offers INNER JOIN seller ON best_offers.seller_id = seller.username WHERE seller.pw='abc'
```